# Get log of function/method calls made by do_action() on WordPress initialization

Tags: hooks, debug, init

Is there any way I can get a log of the method calls that are made when `do_action( 'init')` is fired?

Comment: Are you talking about the function that fired the hook, or the functions that run when the hook is fired?

Comment: The functions that run when the hook is fired. I'm trying to figure out why some methods that have been added to `$wp_filter['init']` aren't being run.

Comment: As a sidenote, the query monitor displays this information, any answer might do well to reference it as an example ( or to research said answer )

Comment: The plugin Debug Objects doing this for you. This view the functions, method, class that was fired. Maybe this helps you. The core have the functions did_action and doing_action as helper for your requirement.

Comment: The Query Monitor plugin does everything I was looking for. I'm just getting used to the WordPress way of doing things. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a way to do this via a plugin (at least in a way that will get around 500 type errors, which is why I originally looked into this), but the section of code where the hook callback gets called is in wp-includes/plugin.php in the do_action function:

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/plugin.php#L453

This got updated in WP 4.7 a bit, but if you edit around this line temporarily, you can do some debugging. Change:

```
$wp_filter[ $tag ]->do_action( $args );
```

To

```
if($tag == "init") echo "Calling " . $args[0] . ".<br />";
$wp_filter[ $tag ]->do_action( $args );
```

And this should echo some info to help you know what callbacks are being called.